# Normalizing Eigenvectors from Pauli Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

For this example of a Pauli matrix, 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -i \\
   i & 0
\end{bmatrix}
I found that one of its eigenvectors (for $\lambda = 1$) is 
\begin{bmatrix}
   -i \\
   1
\end{bmatrix}
but when I try to normalize it, I run into the issue of dividing by zero. Can anyone guess what I'm doing wrong here?

My problem setup: 
$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right)
% 
=
(+1)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right)$

Comment: If you want to know what you're doing wrong you should post your work.

Comment: The real problem you have is that you obviously not know how the inner product in a vector space over the complex numbers is defined. Multiply a vector with its complex conjugated vector componentwise.

Comment: @Fakemistake Where am I going wrong with conjugate symmetry?

Comment: I've deleted my comment, because it was a bad notation. I suggest to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Generalizations) section of the whole article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm of the eigenvector is $$||\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1\end{bmatrix}|| =\sqrt{|-i|^2+|1|^2}=\sqrt{2},$$ therefore the normalization constant is $1 /\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ah I see the difference. That aside, I'm pretty sure the eigenvalues for each of the Pauli matrices are $\pm 1$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues

Comment: GIven those values, ($\lambda = 1$ in particular) I'm only able to come up with the eigenvector I mentioned in my question... though it differs from what I'm seeing from several sources. Are you able to compute a different one?

Comment: @GrantPark Sorry about that, the eigenvalues are in fact $\pm 1$. You have an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$, how did you find it? Recall that any eigenvector $\lambda$ of an operator $A$ has eigenvectors $v$ which satisfy the eigenvalue equation $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: $-iy = x; ix = y; \Rightarrow \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-iy \\
\frac{-iy}{-i}
\end{array} \right) = y \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-i \\
1
\end{array} \right)$

Comment: @GrantPark Where did you get $-iy=x$ from? What is $x$?

Comment: I edited my question just now to include my setup, it's the last expression. If you multiply out the LHS, that's where I got it from.

Comment: @GrantPark So repeat the same calculation with $-1$ instead of $+1$

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your mistake is treating the norm as $$\sqrt{(-i)^2+1^2} = 0$$

It should be $$\sqrt{|-i|^2+|1|^2} = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{|-i|^2+|1|^2}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: oops, thanks, mistake from copy and paste.